# Cannot decode JSON using Core Data class

Tags: swift

I have set up a Core Data entity called Station which has a single string attribute "name". I've generated an NSManagedObject subclass and modified it to be Decodable like so

**Station+CoreDataProperties.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Station {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Station> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Station>(entityName: "Station")
    }
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
}
```

**Station+CoreDataClass.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Station)
public class Station: NSManagedObject, Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext,
            let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Station", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                throw("error message")
        }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
public extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let managedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "managedObjectContext")
}
```

I have the following data in a JSON file 
**stationData.json**

```
[{"name": "Station1"},{"name": "Station2"}]
```

I'm trying to use the following function (taken from an Apple tutorial) to decode the previous JSON file

**Data.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

let stationData: [Station] = load("stationData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String, as type: T.Type = T.self) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("the error is \(error)")
    }
}
```

This function is failing to decode the JSON with the error `Fatal error: the error is error message: file [path to file]/Data.swift, line 33
(lldb)`

If I create a test struct like so,

```
struct StationTest: Decodable {
    var name: String
}
```

and instead do `let stationData: [StationTest] = load("stationData.json")` it will decode correctly. Why does my original Station class not work when decoding? The error message unfortunately isn't helping at all.

Thanks!

Comment: @Desdenova Thank you for linking that article. What I had was 95% similar to them, but I had forgotten the last step of passing the context object `decoder.userInfo[.context] = context`. It works now :)